# Facebook Hash Tag Search in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, hashtag

In the latest version of ios facebook, if you tap a hashtag it launches a hashtag search. I was wondering if the latest version of Facebook SDK or Graph API has any sort of support to do the same search from within our native ios app and receive a json of the results that we would get in the facebook app? If someone can tell me how this can be done that would be super. Thanks a lot.